# Java 8 Filter Predicate Parameter Index Out Of Bounds

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I've been trying to solve this for a while but my **Java 8** skills need a bit of work.

This issue I am having is that in an `IntStream`. I am using a filter to call a predicate which will run some logic on the current item and the next item in the list.

```
return IntStream.range(0, someList.size() - 1)
            .filter(n -> someMethod(someList.get(n), someList.get(n + 1)))
            .mapToObj(i -> ((Integer) i).toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

The problem is that the last item is not checked.

So say I have 10 items in the list the first iteration would look at items 0 and 1, then 1 and 2 etc until we get to 10 and `IndexOutOfBounds`.

No error is thrown here which is strange although probably expected in Java 8?

How can I say something like "*if we get an index out of bounds just return true*"?

I hope this makes sense. Cheers

Comment: You shouldn't try to workaround runtime exceptions like an IndexOutOfBounds. It's a bug. Just fix the bug. It doesn't make sense to try accessing indices outside the bounds of the list. So don't do it.

Comment: As @JBNizet already said, you should not try to work around `IndexOutOfBoundsException` but rather fix the error. However just for the record you could do it with **try-catch**: `try { code that throws the exception } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { code to execute if that happens }`.

Comment: I'm not trying to work around the error. I would be happy if it actually threw the error

Comment: Post real code. That code wouldn't even comple: there is no collect() method accepting a Collector in IntStream. So, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Code updated so it compiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to iterate from `0` to the `size+1`, so for a list of size 3, you're attempting to to:

`list[0]` - valid
`list[1]` - valid
`list[2]` - valid
`list[3]` - OOB, as list is only size 3

Change it to:

```
return IntStream.range(0, someList.size())
    .filter(n -> n < someList.size()-1 ? someMethod(someList.get(n), someList.get(n+1)) : someOtherMethod(someList.get(n)).collect(Collectors.toList));
```

This will fix two things. One, it will fix the OOB you had in `range()`, and two, it will check that `n` is in bounds for calling someMethod for `n` and `n+1`. You'll need to make another method for how you want to handle it for the last element in the list though

Comment: Can you highlight the changes and explain why they solve the issue?

Comment: @JBNizet, whoops sorry, fixed

Comment: That still won't work. someList.get(n+1) will still throw. when n is size - 1.

Comment: Fixed, didn't catch that on my small screen

Comment: Nice! Adding a ternary condition in there fixed it Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Let say someList.size() = 10, so the last element is with index 9. and then you doing something like n+1, which is someList.get(9+1) then  Exception occurs.  It should be someList.size() - 1

`return IntStream.range(0, someList.size()-1)
    .filter(n -> someMethod(someList.get(n), someList.get(n + 1)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());`

And it should work.

Edit: You need to do some checking

```
`   private void invoke() {

    List<String> someList = Arrays.asList("Test", "Super");
    int size = someList.size();

    List<Integer> collect = IntStream.range(0, size)
            .filter(n -> someMethod(someList.get(n), getNext(someList, n + 1)))
            .mapToObj(i -> i)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}

public <T> T getNext(List<T> someList, int index) {
    return someList.size() > index ? someList.get(index) : null;
}


public boolean someMethod(String a1, String a2) {
    return a1.equals(a2);
}
```

Comment: That should work although I'm still not reading the last value. As I said it reads through the list in the following order: index(0) - index(1), index(1) - index(2).....index(10) - index(11 - there is no index 11)

Comment: I refined my answer. now you can copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in range() function is exclusive which means if you set it to be 20 your range will go until 19 (not including 20) that in your case you want to get the index before last so if the last index is size-1 you should pass to function size() if you want to get size-2 you should pass last parameter size-1 here is a simple example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 1).forEach(index -> System.out.println("Me " + list.get(index) + " and my brother " + list.get(index + 1)));
}
```